# Virtual study room in Blender

Tags: vr

I would like to know whether I can create VR game using Blender without any other tools like Unity, Unreal.
My idea is to create a virtual study room for kids using Blender. Outcome: kids will use VR headsets and enter the study room, pick up a book, read it by turning pages.

Answer (score 1):

No, Blender doesn't have such tools. You are able to create content in Blender but not the code. Blender had a BGE in the past, but it was removed. You are going to have to use game engines.

Comment: Note that the old Blender Game engine has been forked as [UBGE}(https://upbge.org/#/).  I wouldn't use UBGE for this purpose, but Blender does have a 3rd party game engine available.